# Loading data stored in a view folder

Tags: javascript, file, asp.net-mvc-4, loading

First off: I know that it is not a good practice to store data, such as images and music files, in the view folder. "It should always go in the content folder".

But here is the thing. My view is a rather enormous javascript system. This system tries to load some resources from a relative folder, which now is my "Home/data/*" view folder. This does not work.

Is there a way to allow the loading of files from these folders?